# Fazer uma marca no próprio mapa do Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de deixar uma marca em certa parte do mapa do Google Maps (android). Não estou dizendo na forma de marcador, estou querendo por exemplo, deixar uma área próxima à minha casa com uma mancha de vermelho no mapa (ou outra cor). É possível fazer isso no android? Obrigado.

Comment: beleza! Mas quando você fizer uma pergunta, tente ser bem claro. Se você tivesse inserido aquela imagem do seu comentário aqui na sua pergunta, eu nem teria adicionado a resposta. Boa sorte!

Comment: Desculpe meu querido . Só pensei em adicionar a imagem depoid, mais de qualquer forma muito obrigado por tentar ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No mapa você pode adicionar referências com addMarker, addCircle, addPolyline e addPolygon.

Na imagem do link foi usado provavelmente addPolygon.

Tem também addGroundOverlay, assim como o circle a polyline e o polygon o ground acompanha o zoom a rotação e a inclinação do mapa.

No exemplo eu desenhei um png 256x256 em forma de estrela. Veja o resultado:

```
       @Override
       public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) 
       {

         GroundOverlayOptions options = new GroundOverlayOptions();
         LatLng latLng = new LatLng("lat","lng"); // posição que deseja adicionar a marca

         options.position(latLng,400,400); // 400 - raio em metros
         options.image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ground));
         options.clickable(false);

         map.addGroundOverlay(options);
      }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá amigo, primeiramente muito obrigado, parece que é isso que eu preciso! Só gostaria de confirmar uma coisa com você: como faço para escolher a posição no mapa dessa imagem? Pq vc escreveu nos 400 que era o raio, então não é a posição onde a estrela fica, certo? Ou esses 400,400 são as coordenadas?

Comment: Tentei criar um "LatLng posicao = new LatLng(-23.557924, -46.660552)" e colocar no "options.position(posicao,400,400);", porém, dá erro na hora de abrir o aplicativo. Provavelmente estou colocando no lugar errado.

Comment: Você baixou a imagem para usar como ground?

Comment: Sim. E adicionei esse código no OnCreate da activity, está no lugar certo? Se precisar edito minha pergunta e posto meu codigo para voce tentar me ajudar

Comment: Poste o código, você adiciona a marca depois e obter a instância do mapa em onMapReady, conforme a postagem do Cleidimar Viana.

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado. Foi vacilo meu mesmo, estava acostumado a colocar as coisas no OnCreate por causa de outros projetos e não me liguei que era no OnMapReady que tinha que colocar. Funcionou perfeitamente, era exatamente isso que eu queria. Muito obrigado pela ajuda de verdade.